# Need help in evaluating the integral $\frac{dx}{(x^4 - 1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, contest-math, indefinite-integrals

**Question:** Evaluate the integral
$$ \int \frac{dx}{(x^4 - 1)^2} $$

I solved this problem using partial fractions, to obtain the answer

$$ \frac{1}{16}\left( \frac{4x}{x^4 - 1} + 6 \tan^{-1}(x) + 3\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)  \right)$$

However the solution was super-long, and so I hoped of finding other methods of solving it by shorter methods. So far I have tried substituting $\sqrt{\sec t}$ for $x$ and it didn't seem to work.

I have also tried substituting $x$ for $\frac{1}{t}$ so that $dx$ = $-\frac{1}{t^2}$, which yields,

$$ \int \frac{-t^8 dt}{t^2 (t^4 - 1)^2} = \int \frac{-t^6 dt}{(t^4 - 1)^2} $$

and I couldn't figure how could I proceed further from this, if it is a plausible approach.

I would like some hints as for how could I proceed through this problem to obtain a shorter solution. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the following integral without using partial fraction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518750/how-to-evaluate-the-following-integral-without-using-partial-fraction) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7B(x%5E4-1)%5E2%7D%24&p=1). Note that solving the same integral is also asked at [How to solve integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2081624).

Comment: yes... thank you for the reference.

Comment: I had solved by fully decomposing the fraction, but an alternative decomposition as $\frac{1}{(x^4 -1)^2}$ as $\frac{1}{((x^2 - 1)(x^2 + 1))^2} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} - \frac{1}{x^2 - 1}\right)\right)^2$  works very well